# Limit of iAd Banners?

Tags: iphone

I am using an iAd Banner for Advertisement .I have two views in single Navigation controller. I know that this would be possible by the creating a global preference class.How many iAd Banner can be added in a single app? I just want to know any other way.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Single iAD Banner per viewcontroller.

Comment: i have added two separate iAd in two different ViewController and its working but will apple accept it?

Comment: As long as you're only showing one iAd banner at a time you're fine.